# VHDL: Add list of numbers using loop

Tags: loops, addition, vhdl

To start off, I have a very limited knowledge of C, just basic functions. I have been set a task in VHDL of which i have no experience.

The task is to write a program in VHDL that will use a loop to add a list of 10 numbers (13,8,6,5,19,21,7,1,12,3).

I was thinking of a way of doing this even in C to see if i could somewhat mimic the method. so far i have only came up with

```
    int start = 0;
    int add = start;
    int increment = 5;

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    add = add + increment;
    }
```

now i know that is VERY basic but it's the best i can do. that loop will only increment it by 5 as apposed to the list that i have.

Any help is very appreciated and it's my first question so apologies i if i am breaking any 'unwritten laws'

Comment: Ah sorry, the task (adding the list of numbers) is to be done in VHDL, as part of our studies on parwan processors. The c part was me simply trying to make an effort at what I know, however rereading, its not terribly relevant sorry

Answer (score 2):

First, I'll point out there's no need to add the complexity of `std_logic_vector`s or vector arithmetic with `signed` and `unsigned`.  This works fine with simple integers:

So, you have some numbers coming in and a sum going out:

```
entity summer
port (
  inputs : integer_vector := (13,8,6,5,19,21,7,1,12,3);
  sum_out : integer);
end entity summer;
```

Note, I've initialise the inputs port with your values - normally you'd write to that port in your testbench.

Now to add them up, you need a process:

```
process(inputs)
    variable sum : integer;
begin
    sum := 0;
    for i in inputs'range loop
        sum := sum + inputs(i);
    end for;
    sum_out <= sum;
end process;
```

That's a simplistic solution - to create a "best" solution you need a more detailed specification.  For example: how often will the inputs change?  How soon do you need the answer after the inputs change?  Is there a clock?

Comment: What libraries did you use??

Comment: I can't see that any libraries are necessary.  You will need a VHDL-2008 tool to use `integer_vector`: https://www.doulos.com/knowhow/vhdl_designers_guide/vhdl_2008/vhdl_200x_small/

Answer (score 1):

The solution below could help you get started with your problem in VHDL:

For the implementation in a FPGA, better solutions could be figured out.  So, just consider it as a start...

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity add is

    port (
        clk : in  std_logic;
        rst : in  std_logic;
        add : in  std_logic;
        sum : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));

end entity add;

architecture RTL of add is

    constant rom_size : integer := 10;
    type     t_rom is array (0 to rom_size-1) of unsigned(31 downto 0);
    constant rom : t_rom := (
        to_unsigned(13, sum'length),
        to_unsigned(8, sum'length),
        to_unsigned(6, sum'length),
        to_unsigned(5, sum'length),
        to_unsigned(19, sum'length),
        to_unsigned(21, sum'length),
        to_unsigned(7, sum'length),
        to_unsigned(1, sum'length),
        to_unsigned(12, sum'length),
        to_unsigned(3, sum'length));
    signal add_d : std_logic;
    signal index : integer range 0 to rom_size;
    signal sum_i : unsigned(sum'range);

begin

    p_add : process (clk) is
    begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then        -- rising clock edge
            if rst = '1' then           -- synchronous reset (active high)
                sum_i <= (others => '0');
                add_d <= '0';
                index <= 0;
            else

                add_d <= add;           -- rising edge detection

                if add_d = '0' and add = '1' then  -- rising_edge -> add next item to sum
                    sum_i <= sum_i + rom(index);
                    index <= index + 1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process p_add;


    -- output
    sum <= std_logic_vector(sum_i);

end architecture RTL;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You mention that this is a part of a study on parwan processors, So the way to think about it depends a lot on how you are studying them.

If you are building up an implementation of the processor than just learning the syntax for logical operations is the important part, and you should focus on the types
`unsigned range 0 to 255` and `signed range -128 to 127`.  By making use of the package `ieee.numeric_std.all` you get the addition operation defined for those types.

If however the processor is already defined for you take a good look at the processor interfaces.  The code you will write for this will be much more of an explicit state machine.

Either way I find the best way to start is to write a test bench.  This is the part that will feed in the list of inputs, because ultimately you wont want it to be a `for (int i=0; i<10; i++)`, but rather a `while(1)` style of processing.

That's all theory stuff, so here's some pseudo code for a simple accumulator process:

```
signal acc : unsigned range 0 to 255 := 0; --accumulator register
signal b : unsigned range 0 to 255 := 5;   --value to be added 
--each cycle you would change b

accumulator :process (clk)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk)
        acc <= acc + b;
    end if;
end process;
```

or maybe better yet take a look here: [Accumulator](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~hepeng/cse143-w08/labs/VHDLTutorial/Accumulator.vhd)